# filtering datagrid

Tags: c#

I m using a datagrid.  When I enter a value in the textbox I want to search that value in the database and display that in the datagrid.

How do i do that?

Comment: What technology? ASP.NET, Winforms?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried databinding?  That should work.